# How to collect a changing variable from a views.py function to the template without reloading in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I am creating a chatbot using django and tflearn, I have to completed the code to some extent, i have been able to post data from the template to the views.py function ('home') using javascript, but the things is i can't collect the current output from the chatbot, it is always returning the first result not the current result, although in the console it print the actual result.

This are my codes.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from .apps import chat
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    result = request.POST.get("data")
    if result == None:
        result = 'hi'
    else:
        result = request.POST.get("data")
    
    print (str(result))
    
    mycontent = chat(str(result))
   
    context = {'mycontent':mycontent}
    
    print (mycontent)

    return render(request, 'alice/index.html', context )
```

index.html

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4 frame">
        <ul></ul>
        <div>
            <form method='POST' id ='post-form'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="msj-rta macro">                        
                    <div class="text text-r" style="background:whitesmoke !important" >
                        <input class="mytext" id='data' name="next"  placeholder="Type a message"/>
                        
                    </div> 

                </div>
                <div style="padding:10px;">
                <button id="button" type= 'submit' name="button" onclick="myFunction()">send</button>
                
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    
                    function myFunction() {
                  insertChat('me',document.getElementById("data").value, 0)
                        insertChat('you', '{{mycontent}}', 0)
                    }
                </script>
                
                
                
                </div>   
            </form>             
        </div>
    </div>       
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var me = {};
me.avatar = "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-lr2nyjhhjXw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAARmE/MdtfUmC0M4s/photo.jpg?sz=48";

var you = {};
you.avatar = "https://a11.t26.net/taringa/avatares/9/1/2/F/7/8/Demon_King1/48x48_5C5.jpg";

function formatAMPM(date) {
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
    return strTime;
}            

//-- No use time. It is a javaScript effect.
function insertChat(who, text, time){
    if (time === undefined){
        time = 0;
    }
    var control = "";
    var date = formatAMPM(new Date());
    
    if (who == "me"){
        control = '<li style="width:100%">' +
                        '<div class="msj macro">' +
                        '<div class="avatar"><img class="img-circle" style="width:100%;" src="'+ me.avatar +'" /></div>' +
                            '<div class="text text-l">' +
                                '<p>'+ text +'</p>' +
                                '<p><small>'+date+'</small></p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</li>';                    
    }else{
        control = '<li style="width:100%;">' +
                        '<div class="msj-rta macro">' +
                            '<div class="text text-r">' +
                                '<p>'+text+'</p>' +
                                '<p><small>'+date+'</small></p>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '<div class="avatar" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 10px !important"><img class="img-circle" style="width:100%;" src="'+you.avatar+'" /></div>' +                                
                  '</li>';
    }
    setTimeout(
        function(){                        
            $("ul").append(control).scrollTop($("ul").prop('scrollHeight'));
        }, time);
    
}

function resetChat(){
    $("ul").empty();
}

$(".mytext").on("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        var text = $(this).val();
        if (text !== ""){
            insertChat("me", text);              
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }
});

$('body > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > span').click(function(){
    $(".mytext").trigger({type: 'keydown', which: 13, keyCode: 13});
})

//-- Clear Chat
resetChat();


$(document).on('submit', '#post-form',function(e){

    
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'',
        data:{
            data:$('#data').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            action: 'post'
        },
        

        
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    },
        
    });

    
    e.preventDefault();
});
```